# How to align the text in middle of the screen

Tags: html, css

I want to align text in middle of the screen. I have content and button within a `div` element that I want to display in the middle of the screen.

Right now, the text appears below the `div` element.

I have three banner and and 3 content.

I want to align the text in middle in both vertical and horizontal.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 var headerheight = jQuery("#header-wrapper").height();
 jQuery(".view-home-banner .views-row-1 .panell img").css("margin-top",headerheight+"px");
 jQuery(".banner_img img").addClass("img-responsive");
});
```

```css
#navigation
{
 display:none;
}
.feed-icon
{
 display:none;
}
/*banner*/
#home_banner .home-banner {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
     color:black;
}
.banner_description p { font-weight: bold;word-spacing:5px;margin:1%}
.banner_link {
 font-size: 28pt
     
 text-align: center;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
 }
.banner_description {
 
 font-size: 33pt;
 font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
     text-align:center;
 
}
.banner_link a { 
 color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: normal;
 background-position:1%;
 padding:0.5% 1.5%;
 background-color:#5d145f;
 font-size:17pt;
 opacity:0.8;
}
.background-image-formatter {
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
 min-height: 100vh;
}
.home-banner-background
{
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
 border-radius:2%;
 opacity:0.9;
}
/*.banner_img > img{
    /*float: right;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
min-height: 100vh;
}
.banner_img > img {
    max-height: 1024px;
    min-width: 1024px;
}
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first classtest">
    <section class="panell" style="height: 543px;">
        <span class="field-content banner_img"><div class="background-image-formatter" style="background-image: url('data:image/jpeg;base64,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')">
  &nbsp;
</div>
</span>  <div class="home-banner-background">
        <div class="field-content banner_description"><p>We built great software products</p>
</div>     <div class="field-content banner_link"><a href="#">Explore</a></div>    </div>
      </section>
    
 </div>
```

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is, in the fiddle the text is in the middle of the screen using `text-align:center`. Is that not what you want?

Comment: I want to align the vertical height.

Comment: Then please specify that in the question, it's not clear what you want by reading it.

Comment: you have used `#header-wrapper` in a jquery func, but i can't see such thing in your html!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to align a div in the middle of the screen, you can set `margin : 0, auto;` and `width:50%;` for the CSS of the div.This is a famous CSS trick.Btw, your question is confusing and please reduce your question content to minimum.

**Edit:** Based on the comment that was left, you are trying to align horizontally and vertically.You can do the following:

```
div {

     transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     position: absolute;
}
```

This will dynamiclly align your element.From Mozilla Developers:

```
translatex()
The translateX() CSS function moves the element horizontally on the plane. This transformation is characterized by a <length> defining how much it moves horizontally.
translateX(tx) is a shortcut for translate(tx, 0).
translatey()
The translateY() CSS function moves the element vertically on the plane. This transformation is characterized by a <length> defining how much it moves vertically.
translateY(ty) is a shortcut for translate(0, ty).
```

See more about the transformation function [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function)

Comment: this is not the answer, he wants to align something both horizontally and vertically!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make text center horizontally then you can use `text-align:center` in case you want to do it vertically you can use `line-height` property. you have given `height:543px` to section so you need to write

```
line-height:543px ;
```

here is updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1mh33zz7/